# PHP use pipe and stdin from user input

Tags: php, command-line-interface

When running

```
ls | php script.php
```

`fgets(STDIN)` is not waiting for user input:

```
<?php 
$pipe = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
echo "Enter something";
$line = fgets(STDIN);
```

But if I run

```
php script2.php
```

With script2.php :

```
<?php 
echo "Enter something";
$line = fgets(STDIN);
```

The script pauses waiting for my input. 
How can I get pipe & wait for user input?

Answer (score 0):

Instead use [readline](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) function of php, it will work fine,

```
$string=readline("Enter value: ");
echo $string;
```

Comment: I don't have readline enabled on my server :(
And I'm not able to enable it :((